# url NotFoundError with quandl

Tags: python, quandl

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'wsnt2aKcnkNMJjdqqwTz'

pd = quandl.get('BATS / BATS_GOOGL')

print(df.head())
```

Error:

> NotFoundError: (Status 400) (Quandl Error QECx01) We could not recognize the URL you requested: /api/v3/datasets/BATS / BATS_GOOGL/data. Please check your URL and try again.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you, this time); also, question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use spaces in the path; also, you should *not* use `pd` as a variable name (remember, you have imported pandas as `pd`), plus that, as is now, you are asking for the `head()` of a dataframe `df` that is nowhere defined.

Try with

```
df = quandl.get('BATS/BATS_GOOGL')
```